# How do I do a Mann Whitney U test when comparing treated and control but control is always 100%?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am trying to test whether the difference between my treatment and control group is significant, however the only way I can compare my results across my 6 independent experiments is through doing percentage of control. This makes all my untreated results 100. Please help

Comment: Why do you need to do percentage of control?